# Is there a way to get the Google Chat app membership in a space?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chat, google-chat-api

We created a chat bot and added it to a space.
When we use [spaces.members.list](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list) REST API it shows only the membership of users in the space and not the chat app.

Is there any other way / API available to get the chat membership ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Chat app"?

Comment: Chat app is the bot for the Google chat. In a Space if the chat app is added then it is also a member for the Space. But spaces.members.list REST API retrieves only the membership of the users in the space.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.